# How to add entries with slapadd in openldap replication(synrepl)

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

We have openldap replication with syncrepl, I don't know how to add slapadd entries into it.

On standalone it works fine. but when i add entries in one of the machine in replication, second machines fails to start slapd.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately slapadd doesn't write to the accesslog and thus the modifications aren't replicable. This is especially bad, because some attributes can't be modified via ldapadd.

If you only need ordinary attributes, use ldapadd instead.

UPDATE:
It looks like you can use the -w switch:

> Write syncrepl context information. After all entries are added, the
>   contextCSN will be updated with the greatest CSN in the database.

Comment: I tried with -w switch, i am able to restore the users. But it broke the replication. another node is failed on restart